# Back to top of current section after seamless-replace pagination (Webflow)

Tags: javascript, webflow

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.pjax/2.0.1/jquery.pjax.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var containerSelector = '#seamless-replace';
  $(document).pjax(
    '.w-pagination-wrapper a',
    containerSelector,
    {
      container: containerSelector, 
      fragment: containerSelector,
      scrollTo: false,
      timeout: 2500,
    }
  );
    // These 3 lines should reinitialize interactions
  $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    Webflow.require('ix2').init();
  });


</script>
```

This is the custom workaround for the pagination in Webflow. Unfortunately the seamless replace is only working for pagination with one row as it stays in the same place. For lists like here it lands with the reload on the bottom of the list or even the element below.

Is there a possibilty to scroll back to either the last `<h2>` or the top of the current class name (`list_repertoire`)?

Big thanks in advance!